# Computer Game - Opens with meeting a famous person and chasing a robber who vanishes using magic

Tags: story-identification, video-games, medieval

I played this PC game almost 16-19 years ago at my grandma's house, so I hope my memory is not too terrible, but here goes:

PLOT

- I made it like 10 minutes into the game until I got stuck, so I do not know any cool plot details
- It opens with the main character (in first person) outside some famous person's house, when the wife comes out with a baby and tells you that the famous guy will see you shortly.
- If you walked away from the lady talking, her voice became more quiet (I want to say like *Skyrim*).
- The house was on top of a cliff, the setting is medieval-esque.
- The animation reminded me of the mode selection screen for *Total Annihilation: Kingdoms* (where there is the knight, the lady with the book, and the war machine) (That's why I think medieval because the wife was dressed in a similar 14th Century dress).

THEN

- The famous guy comes out, talks to you, but then he sees a robber going through his papers, take something, but as we charge the robber, he uses magic to disappear.
- Then all I remember is that I touched some purple light emanating from the floor, I got magically transported somewhere, and then I could not figure out how to progress at all and gave up.

Context Clues

- I played this game around the same time as I played *Spy Kids Learning Adventures: Mission: The Underground Affair* and *TA Kingdoms*, but my grandma probably bought all 3 at the same time from Staples.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This sounds very much like the prologue sequence of *Myst III: Exile*.

You were greeted by Katran (Catherine from the original Myst games), holding their daughter Yeesha, and were visiting Atrus (who had invited you after completion of his house in Tomahna, because you're the same character who helped him in *Myst* and *Riven*).  You missed the part where the thief sets fire to Atrus's house just before "linking" and follow him through the linking book to the prison age his family had been stuck in for a lifetime.

The actual setting is much more recent, but Atrus isn't from our Earth (and neither is Katran, though she's not from Atrus's home world, either).